# Calculated Item for Calculating Memory Usage as a Percentage in Zabbix

Tags: zabbix

In Zabbix I am trying to show total memory in use as a percentage.

I try and create a calculated item with the formula:
((vm.memory.size[active])/(vm.memory.size[total]))*100

This creates the item, yet when I check it's status it says "Not Supported".

Is there something wrong with calculated item? This is just an example, but I've also had problems with creating calculated items, it always says "Not Supported".

Comment: If you hover your mouse over the red cross on the right in the item list, what does it say?

Comment: Format error or unsupported operator. Exp: [vm.memory.size[active]]

Answer (score 4):

There is a built in item for this `vm.memory.size[pused]`

```
Type: Numeric (float) 
Units: % 
Use custom multiplier: 1 
Update interval (in sec): 30
```

[Zabbix Memory Usage in %](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWWQC.png)

For more information check zabbix doc:

https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.2/manual/appendix/items/vm.memory.size_params

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to refer to the last values of these items, you should use `last()` function:

```
(last(vm.memory.size[active]) / last(vm.memory.size[total])) * 100
```

Please see [Zabbix documentation on calculated items](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.4/manual/config/items/itemtypes/calculated) for more details.

Comment: Still says Not Supported. Sorry for the delayed response; have been working on Grafana-Zabbix hookup the past few weeks. The error now is: Cannot evaluate function [last()]: item [subcass001A-cimr:vm.memory.size[active]] not found. I am creating this calculated item on a host named subcass001A-cimr

Comment: Does item "vm.memory.size[active]" exist on host "subcass001A-cimr"? In order for this calculated item to work, both "vm.memory.size[active]" and "vm.memory.size[total]" have to exist on this host and receive values.